# Terminal at MBP when it wasn't previously?

Tags: terminal

Before, my terminal command line looked something like:

~ myname$

But now for no reason it looks like

Name-MBP:~ myname$

And I can't commit things to svn. How can I fix this?

Comment: What does `echo $ZSH_VERSION` produce? And what command are you attempting to run to commit to svn?

Comment: ```echo $ZSH_VERSION``` just prints a new line, and I'm trying to run ```svn commit -m"commit message"``` to commit to a repository set up by my school.

Comment: What does `echo $BASH_VERSION` produce and what does `which svn` produce?

Comment: ```echo $BASH_VERSION``` doesn't produce anything, and ```which svn``` produces ```/usr/bin/svn```

Comment: That's interesting that both BASH and ZSH return nothing. I'd think you are running one of those. Also, the fact that svn returns a value means your path is right. I figured your issue would be with path. What is your actual error? Also I'm assuming you have a space between -m and the commit message.

Comment: What do you mean by "what is your actual error?" I do not have a space between -m and the commit message, if that matters.

Comment: svn commit -m "commit message" - What is the response? And yes there should be a space I think.

Comment: I am getting no response for ```svn commit -m "commit message"```...and I haven't been using a space until now, so I think that's ok.

Comment: It's not okay. `-m` is a parameter passed in. `-m"commit` isn't a command. It's parsed as `svn` `commit` `-m"commit`  `message"`. And you are saying that when you hit enter nothing happens?

Comment: Hmmm...ok, I tried that and it didn't work either, unfortunately.

Comment: And yes, when I hit enter nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

You have somehow switched to `bash`.

Type `zsh` to try.

If that works, change the setting in Terminal's preferences (General -> Shells open with: "Default login shell") (or `/bin/zsh`)

Comment: zsh did not work....and it doesn't say ```(bash) Name-MBP:~ myname$```, it just says ```Name-MBP:~ myname$```